# nvd3 set scale from big to small

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a simple line graph where the Y value spans from 0-100. I want to reverse the Y range to go instead to 100-0. Graph code is below:

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
      var values = that.getGraphValues();
      console.log(values);
      var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
          .forceY([100, 1]);

      chart.xAxis
          .axisLabel('Date')
          .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%b %d')(new Date(d)); });

      chart.yAxis
          .axisLabel('Ranking')
          .tickFormat(d3.format(',r'));

      d3.select('#chart svg')
          .datum(values)
        .transition().duration(500)
          .call(chart);

      nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart svg').call(chart) });

      return chart;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the domain of the graph explicitly.  In D3 terms "domain" is the expected extent of the data.  If you don't set it yourself, it is calculated as `[minValue, maxValue]`.  But you can explicitly set it to anything, even such that the first number is bigger than the second number.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .yDomain([100,0]);
```

Comment: P.S.  `.forceX([numbers])` and `forceY([numbers])` force the domain to *include* those numbers, which can be used to extend the domain, but their order is ignored -- the program just calculates the maximum and minimum values after adding those numbers onto the end of the array of numbers from the data.

Comment: From what I understood, forceX([numbers]) still won't reverse the order. Tried it though, and yes it still doesn't reverse the order.

Comment: @AceDimasuhid Exactly.  I just mentioned it to try to explain why that approach *didn't* work.  Setting the y-domain directly should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use the [Angular NVD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) wrapper, the way to set the custom message is through chart options, simply:

```
$scope.options = {
  chart: {
  ...
  yDomain: [100, 1],
  ...
  }
};
```